# How to select original geometry from empty space?

Tags: 3d-printing

Yes, I know, yet another beginner question.

I've bought a 3D printer a couple of weeks ago. After working on it and trying to make it work and stable, I've decided to start creating my own STL files so I can print whatever I want. So far, creating small and easy stuff isn't that bad. Although, Editing, is.

I've downloaded an STL file from Thingiverse. Even if so far I like the design, I'm trying to edit it and it's not going so well. I'm currently trying to split up the forms the actual designer used to make this. The first cavity on the left seems like a rectangle. The big middle slot, is a rectangle with round corners. The right slot is looking like a cone.

All these forms are kind of reversed into the box, and I am trying to select this Reversed form, so I can change its dimensions or edit it as I want (ie. Make the left slot bigger, make the right cone smaller, ...) . My actual goal is to modify one of the sphere-shaped corners of the big middle slot so it becomes a hollow cylinder, but like I was saying I can't seem to even select the "Sphere" at this place. I am using Absolute values as these needs to be quite precise.

What can I possibly do to make it work ? Thank you for your help !

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you want a boolean operation. This can be applied as a modifier, but I'm reluctant to elaborate because I barely know my way around Blender myself.

Comment: So far, Every posts I saw need a boolean operation to make things work. I'm gonna be honnest, I'm not very good at maths so I'm not sure I understand how it works. It sounds like mission impossible to me, because I know 3D-editing is far from being easy, s/o to all the editors ! lol